# Disable skip-proofs warnings in ACL2

Tags: acl2

How do I disable skip-proofs warnings in ACL2?  Including books that intentionally have lots of skipped proofs can be quite verbose.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the following.

```
(set-inhibit-warnings "skip-proofs")
```

You may wish to place it in your ~/acl2-customization.lisp file.